# Docker container and docker host xdebug conflict

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I have a PHP-FPM docker container (php 7.2) with a service exposing REST API inside and xdebug 2.6 installed in the container. This is the xdebug config:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_host=hostmachine
```

Now I also have xdebug installed at the docker host, that is my desktop. And I'm trying to debug an API client on the docker host. The client connects to the container exposing the API. Everything hangs after sending a request from the API client to the container.

In the following code sample the assignment `$test=1` is never executed if my IDE is listening for incoming debugger connections (no debug configs selected), everything hangs after stepping into `$response = $this->httpClient->get('info')` (`$httpClient` is guzzle http 6.3 btw):

```
public function getInfo(): InfoInterface
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->get('info');
        $test = 1;
    }
```

I was thinking that the xdebug in the container is trying to connect to my IDE, that's the reason of the hanging. But then how can I debug my API client without the container's xdebug interference?

Comment: I think I ended up changing the port so that this didn't conflict, so perhaps `xdebug.remote_port=9001`

Comment: It's possible that Xdebug also tries to debug your API(?) request `$this->httpClient->get('info')`, so it creates a second debug connection. (Although you xdebug settings should not allow such behavior. Check xdebug log for details). But since IDE handles just one such connection at a time .. it's stuck in a waiting queue. I see you have `xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM`. If IDE is indeed PhpStorm .. then try increasing the max debug connections in Settings (set `3` instead of default `1`). If I'm right about the reasoning ... then it should help.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks man, that worked, but with a weird break with the IDE saying it couldn't find the source position. I guess I also need to use the different port to separate the connections from the container and the host, as suggested in the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used a different port for the connections from the docker container and/or increase the max debug connections in the IDE as it's been suggested in the first two comments to the original question.